# Problem with Ocaml and make: "Error: the file ____.cmxa is not a compilation unit description"

Tags: ocaml, coq

I'm running make in the top level of the UniMath directory and make keeps returning errors. I'm working on fedora 35 and I'm using Ocaml version 4.11.2.

Here is a print out of the errors

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rymndbkr/UniMath/sub/coq'
OCAMLBEST -o bin/coqdep_boot
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: tools/coqdep_boot.cmx is not a compilation unit description.
OCAMLBEST -o bin/ocamllibdep
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: tools/ocamllibdep.cmx is not a compilation unit description.
COQMKTOP -o bin/coqtop.opt
File "topbin/coqtop_bin.ml", line 11, characters 20-32:
11 | let drop_setup () = Mltop.remove ()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Mltop
make[2]: *** [Makefile.build:422: bin/coqtop.opt] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rymndbkr/UniMath/sub/coq'
make[1]: *** [Makefile.make:178: submake] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rymndbkr/UniMath/sub/coq'
Makefile:76: .coq_makefile_output.conf: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:247: sub/coq/bin/coq_makefile] Error 2
```

I'll describe the process I went through in hopes that it is reproducible. I was following the UniMath installation instructions on their github (https://github.com/UniMath/UniMath/blob/master/INSTALL.md). They did not have any installation instructions for fedora so I attempted to convert their Debian instructions. The main thing they wanted Debian users to do was run the command

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential git ocaml ocaml-nox ocaml-native-compilers camlp5 libgtk2.0 libgtksourceview2.0 liblablgtk-extras-ocaml-dev ocaml-findlib libnum-ocaml-dev emacs
```

To convert this, I made sure I had Ocaml version 4.11.2. I just followed the steps on Ocaml's site (https://ocaml.org/docs/install.html). There was a script which prompted me to modify ~/.bash_profile. I said yes. I also said yes when it prompted me to add a hook.

I also installed ocaml-num via the command dnf since this was required for later versions of ocaml.

I also installed @development-tools via dnf since another stack exchange post recommended it as the best fedora equivalent of build-essentials, the latter of which is part of the downloads for prepping a Debian computer for UniMath.

There are some things I did not mention that the UniMath site said to install to prep a Debian computer. I either had these things (or their equivalents installed) or could not figure out if they had equivalents.

I decided to just go ahead and try to finish the installation. I simply ran

```
git clone https://github.com/UniMath/UniMath
cd \UniMath
make BUILD_COQIDE=yes
```

It is on the last of these commands that the errors arose.

P.S. - Please let me know if there is information I should add to this question, or any way to improve it.

Comment: Normally we ask for a minimal reproducible example of the error, that we can easily verify and hopefully debug on our computers. If not available, at least instructions on steps to reproduce the original error: what to download, what to run, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Yawar I updated it with the process I followed.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `not a compilation unit description` is likely due to a mismatch between the Ocaml version that compiled the file and the one that is trying to read it.

You can use `ocamlobjinfo` to check that hypothesis.

A possible fix is to use `make clean` to reinitialize the state, and then rebuild it after ensuring that the environment is consistent with a call to `eval $(opam env)`.

Comment: I went to one of the problem files and ran ocamlobjinfo. It returned a message saying that the file was not an Ocaml object file. I think this confirms your hypothesis. But I ran make clean in the top level of the directory and all that happened was it returned the same errors.

Comment: This means that there two OCaml installation in scope somehow. Did you try `make distclean`? The configuration might have picked the wrong OCaml compiler? Did you check that `ocamlc -v` returns the expected version number?

Comment: both `ocamlc --version` and `ocaml --version` return 4.11.2, as wanted. I do have more than one version of ocaml install so this may be contributing to the problem. 

I ran `make distclean` and the same problem comes up.

Comment: Looking at it more, I have ocaml 4.11.2 installed through the process I described. I also have ocaml 4.12.0 which is downloaded through `dnf`.

Comment: As a confirmation, you can check through the ocamlobjinfo installed on your system that the anomalous cmx file are compiled through the system OCaml compiler. After that, it will be unfortunately a matter of debugging the Makefile to understand why the system compiler is even invoked.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for all the help. I'll see what I can do.